# tkinter key inputs not running assigned function when called

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been trying to write some tkinter code that makes a circle onscreen light up white when the "a" key is held down, but then reverts to normal once the key is released. however, neither pressing the "a" key or releasing it seems to anything at all. please may someone help with this?

here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
window_width = 200
window_height = 200
window = Tk()
screen_width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = window.winfo_screenheight()
x = (screen_width / 2) - (window_width / 2)
y = (screen_height / 2) - (window_height / 2) - (screen_height / 20)
canvas = Canvas(window, width=window_width, height=window_height, bg="#000000")
canvas.pack()
window.title("Test")
window.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (window_width, window_height, x, y))

circle = canvas.create_oval(0, 0, 200, 200, width=5, outline="#FFFFFF")

def a_key_press(event=None):
    canvas.itemconfig(circle, fill="#FFFFFF")
    print("pressed")
    window.update()
def a_key_release(event=None):
    canvas.itemconfig(circle, fill="#000000")
    print("released")
    window.update()


window.bind('<KeyPress-A>', a_key_press())
window.bind('<KeyRelease-A>', a_key_release())

window.mainloop()
```

thanks in advance for the help :D

Comment: *You* called `button_press()` and `button_release()` yourself, once each, and passed their return values (which are probably None) as the function to call when the key event occurs.  You don't want the `()` after each function, you want to pass the functions themselves.

Comment: Also change <KeyPress-A> and <KeyRelease-A> to <KeyPress-a> and <KeyRelease-a> for it to be consistent with the event name. Or change the event name to an "A" if you want the circle to light up when the capital letter is typed via Shift or Capslock

Comment: Also note that you're binding now to capital A instead of lower case a. This code snippet works for me after I changed to `window.bind('<KeyPress-A>', a_key_press)` and `window.bind('<KeyRelease-A>', a_key_release)` like @jasonharper mentioned. (I did have to click the tkinter window first to make it the active window.)

Answer (score 1):

Change the keybinds to:

```py
window.bind('<KeyPress-a>', a_key_press)
window.bind('<KeyRelease-a>', a_key_release)
```

The change from uppercase 'A' to lowercase 'a', makes the binds to the normal 'a' press. You could leave it in uppercase if you want to bind to shift-a for example.

In the bind method you have to pass a reference to the function you want to bind, and not call the function itself. Hence there should be no brackets after the function.